# Distribution of sodium–potassium pumps

Tags: neuroscience, neurophysiology

How are [sodium–potassium pumps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Na%2B/K%2B-ATPase) distributed over the membrane of a neuron? Where are the most, where are the fewest? Or does this dependent on the type of neuron?

Are there known and understandable correlations between the local densities of  sodium–potassium pumps and other membrane molecules (like ligand-gated or voltage-gated ion channels)?